# Laptop memory "on BD"?

Tags: memory

Whilst browsing for a [new laptop](http://www.ebuyer.com/523414-samsung-780z5e-laptop-np780z5e-t01uk), I came across a new memory configuration:

- 8GB DDR3 1600MHz
- Configuration 4GB x 1 + 4GB on BD
- 1 x DIMM slot

It looks like a single RAM slot with 8GB, filled with a 4GB stick, but then with "+ 4GB on BD".

What is this 4GB on BD?

Comment: It basically means. Only a single stick can be replaced. One of the modules is using an intergrated soldered solution.  Of course I can already tell you that 8GB is likely the highest amount of memory that laptop supports anyways.

Comment: Reading the manual is always a great way to understand the specifications of a product.  http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/201303/20130328093014562/Win8_Manual_eng.pdf